# Create a pchs vector with the argument values for + and x

Tags: r, vector

I have done creating a vector by

```
pch <- c("+","*")
pch
```

but unable to understand exact question.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely in context with `plot`, e.g.

```
pch <- c("+","*")
plot(1:2, xlim=c(.5, 2.5), ylim=c(0, 3), pch=pch)
```

[image]